# Simple test with selenium HTMLUnitDriver do not work fine, is it wrong?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

I am a beginner with selenium, I am doing a test but I do not understand why it does not work.
Here are my code and the following error.

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.*;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
 public class PruebaHTMLUnit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
element.sendKeys("Guru99");
element.submit();
System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

driver.quit();
}
}
```

And the error:

> ```
> Build info: version: '3.5.2', revision: '10229a9', time: '2017-08-21T17:29:55.15Z'
> System info: host: 'MVILLEGAS764', ip: '169.254.106.219', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
> ```
>
> '1.8.0_144'
>       Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
>         at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementByName(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1293)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:303)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$4.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1970)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$4.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1606)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1966)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:754)
>         at com.villegas.pruebas.PruebasRegresion.PruebaHTMLUnit.main(PruebaHTMLUnit.java:20)

Comment: Add this to your question, say clearly what does not work and how it should work, add proper markdown formatting for code.

Comment: WHich jar is u are using

Comment: How can I know which jar i'm using?

Comment: Right click on Project -->go to build path-->add external jars

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

    public class test_Stackoverflow
    {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                       WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
                driver.get("https://www.google.com");
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gs_htif0']"));
                element.sendKeys("Guru99");
                element.submit();
                System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
                driver.quit();
            }
    }
```

HtmlUnitDriver was a part of Selenium version 2.53. If you are using Selenium 2.52 or earlier you don't need to download and install HtmlUnitDriver, it is already there.

But still you want to use it download it from here

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/releases

From 2.53 version, you need to add it separately

See this image [image: Image of result]

Try this:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-htmlunit-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.52.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How can i know which selenium I'm using? I thnk <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Right click on Project -->go to build path-->add external jars

Comment: You are using 3.5.1

Comment: USe this <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-htmlunit-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.52.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: TRY THIS @mvillegas and let me know

Comment: System info: host: 'MVILLEGAS764', ip: '169.254.106.219', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
 at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementByName(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1293)
 at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:303)
 at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$4.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1970)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one hope it will works

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.*;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
    /**
     * Created by W3E64 on 9/15/2017.
     */
    public class testing_solution
    {
public static void main(String[] args) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
 HtmlUnitDriver unitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

 unitDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 unitDriver.get("http://google.com");
 System.out.println("Title of the page is -> " + unitDriver.getTitle());

 WebElement searchBox = unitDriver.findElement(By.name("q"))
 searchBox.sendKeys("Selenium");
 WebElement button = unitDriver.findElement(By.name("btnG"));
 button.click();
 System.out.println("Title of the page is -> " + unitDriver.getTitle());
            }
    }
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element with name: q
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z'
System info: host: 'MVILLEGAS764', ip: '169.254.106.219', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver

Comment: WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.class("gsfi")); use this line insted of name

Comment: Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
 at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementByCssSelector(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1252)
 at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementByClassName(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1224)
 at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByClassName.findElement(By.java:391)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using submit() method use either a click on the google search button or input an Enter key in the search box. I have tried running the code above and it worked fine. I am using Selenium 3.141.59 with HtmlUnitDriver 2.36.0. The behaviour of HtmlUnitDriver varies with versions. The second method is a lot simpler and I personally prefer that:

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Write this instead of submit and it will work fine.